# Conversion Error for request type APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyRequest in .net6 (migrating from .net core 3.1 to .net6)

Tags: serialization, lambda, serverless

**Error:** System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'System.IO.MemoryStream' cannot be converted to type 'Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents.APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyRequest'. at System.RuntimeType.TryChangeType(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, Boolean needsSpecialCast) at System.RuntimeType.CheckValue(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, BindingFlags invokeAttr)at System.Reflection.MethodBase.CheckArguments(StackAllocedArguments& stackArgs, ReadOnlySpan`1 parameters, Binder binder, BindingFlags invokeAttr, CultureInfo culture, Signature sig)

**Error Occured while updating following package:**

```
1) Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson
V2.1.0 ---> v2.3.1
and 
2. Amazon.Lambda.Core
v2.0.0--->v2.1.0
```

**Serverless Lambda handler code**

```
//using namespaces

namespace ProjectAPI.Commands.Functions
  {
   public class External : EntryFunction
   {
       public async Task<APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyResponse> CreateRunBookingAsync(APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyRequest request, ILambdaContext context)
         {
        try
        {
            var command = request.GetBodyAs<CreateRetryBatchPushLocusCommand>();
            var response = await Send(request, command);
            return ProxyResponse(response, context?.Logger);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var response = new EntryExceptionResponse(e);
            return ProxyResponse(response, context?.Logger);
        }
   }
}
```

}

**Base Class : EntryFunction**

```
//using namespaces
namespace ProjectAPI.Commands {
public class EntryFunction : BaseEntryFunction {
    protected override BaseDependencyResolver BaseDependencyResolver => new DependencyResolver();

    protected override IMediator ProvideMediatorInstance() {
        return BaseDependencyResolver.ServiceProvider.GetService<IMediator>();
    }
  }}
```

**Base Class: BaseEntryFunction**

```
//using namespaces

[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(SourceGeneratorLambdaJsonSerializer<Common.API.HttpApiJsonSerializerContext>))]

namespace Common.API
{

[JsonSerializable(typeof(APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyRequest))]
[JsonSerializable(typeof(APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyResponse))]
public partial class HttpApiJsonSerializerContext : JsonSerializerContext
{
}
public abstract class BaseEntryFunction
{
    protected IMediator mediator;

    protected IConfiguration Configuration => BaseDependencyResolver.ServiceProvider.GetService<IConfiguration>();

    protected abstract BaseDependencyResolver BaseDependencyResolver { get; }

    protected BaseEntryFunction()
    {

    }

    protected virtual IMediator ProvideMediatorInstance()
    {
        mediator??=BaseDependencyResolver.ServiceProvider.GetService<IMediator>();
        return mediator;
    }    
    protected Task<TResponse> Send<TResponse>( APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyRequest proxyRequest, IRequest<TResponse> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default )
    {
        return mediator.Send(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}

}
```

**I have following code for resolving dependencies**

```
  //using statements

namespace DependencyResolution.Queries
{
 public class DependencyResolver : BaseDependencyResolver
 {
     public DependencyResolver(Action<IServiceCollection> registerServices = null) : base(registerServices)
    {

    }

    protected override void ConfigureServices(ServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        serviceCollection.AddTransient<IEnvironmentService, EnvironmentService>();
        serviceCollection.AddTransient<IConfigurationService, ConfigurationService>
            (provider => new ConfigurationService(provider.GetService<IEnvironmentService>())
            {
                CurrentDirectory = CurrentDirectory
            });
       
        // Register DbContext class
        //dbcotext registration here 
   ...............
        var intermediateServiceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
        var configService = intermediateServiceProvider.GetService<IConfigurationService>();
        var configuration = configService?.GetConfiguration();
        serviceCollection.ConfigureDatabase(configuration);
        var applicationAssembly = typeof(GetCustomerQuery).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
        var sharedAssembly = typeof(AppRequest<>).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
        //serviceCollection.AddMediatR(applicationAssembly, sharedAssembly);
        serviceCollection.AddMediatR(cfg => cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssemblies(applicationAssembly, sharedAssembly));

        serviceCollection.AddFluentValidation(new[] { applicationAssembly, sharedAssembly });
        RegisterServices?.Invoke(serviceCollection);
    }

}
```

}

**Request Payload is similar to below payload**

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "routeKey": "$default",
  "rawPath": "/path/to/resource",
  "rawQueryString": 
"parameter1=value1&parameter1=value2&parameter2=value",
  "cookies": [ "cookie1", "cookie2" ],
  "headers": {
    "Header1": "value1",
    "Header2": "value2"
  },
  "queryStringParameters": {
    "parameter1": "value1,value2",
    "parameter2": "value"
  },
  "requestContext": {
    "accountId": "123456789012",
    "apiId": "api-id",
    "authentication": {
      "clientCert": {
        "clientCertPem": "CERT_CONTENT",
        "subjectDN": "www.example.com",
        "issuerDN": "Example issuer",
        "serialNumber": "a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1",
        "validity": {
          "notBefore": "May 28 12:30:02 2019 GMT",
          "notAfter": "Aug  5 09:36:04 2021 GMT"
        }
      }
    },
    "authorizer": {
      "jwt": {
    "claims": {
      "claim1": "value1",
      "claim2": "value2"
    },
    "scopes": [ "scope1", "scope2" ]
  }
},
"domainName": "id.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
"domainPrefix": "domain-id",
"http": {
  "method": "POST",
  "path": "/path/to/resource",
  "protocol": "HTTP/1.1",
  "sourceIp": "IP",
  "userAgent": "agent"
},
"requestId": "request-id",
"routeId": "route-id",
"routeKey": "$default-route",
"stage": "$default-stage",
"time": "12/Mar/2020:19:03:58 +0000",
"timeEpoch": 1583348638390
  },
  "body": "Hello from Lambda",
  "pathParameters": { "parameter1": "value1" },
  "isBase64Encoded": false,
  "stageVariables": {
  "stageVariable1": "value1",
    "stageVariable2": "value2"
  }
}
```